# C++ - copy-on-write basic implementation

Tags: c++, copy-on-write

We are supposed to use copy-on-write on our school project. I've been experimenting with a very simple class, but without any luck. I have this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class CPerson {
   public:
            CPerson ();
            CPerson (const CPerson&);
           ~CPerson (); 
      char* m_name;
      char* m_surname;
      int   m_refs;

      void  rename (const char*, const char*);
};

CPerson :: CPerson () : m_name(NULL), m_surname(NULL), m_refs(1) {}

CPerson :: CPerson (const CPerson& src) : m_name (src.m_name), m_surname (src.m_surname), m_refs(src.m_refs+1) {} // supposed to be a shallow copy

CPerson :: ~CPerson () {
   if (m_refs == 1) {
      delete [] m_name;
      delete [] m_surname;
   }
   else --m_refs;
}

void CPerson :: rename (const char* name, const char* surname) {
   delete [] m_name;
   delete [] m_surname;

   m_name = new char [strlen(name)+1];
   m_surname = new char [strlen(surname)+1];

   strcpy (m_name, name);
   strcpy (m_surname, surname);
}

int main () {
   CPerson a;
   a.rename ("Jack", "Smith");
   cout << a.m_name << " " << a.m_surname << endl;

   CPerson b(a);
   cout << a.m_name << " " << a.m_surname << endl;
   cout << b.m_name << " " << b.m_surname << endl;
   // good so far...

   a.rename ("John", "Anderson"); // should rename both 'a' and 'b'
   cout << a.m_name << " " << a.m_surname << endl;
   cout << b.m_name << " " << b.m_surname << endl;   

   // prints random values



   return  0;
}
```

It is strange because when I take out the couts, everything works OK (no leaks, no errors by valgrind).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your implementation falls to pieces with this simple code:  `int main() {     CPerson* a = new CPerson;    CPerson b(*a);    delete a;    cout << b.m_name; }`  In other words, first created one is destroyed, but the second (`b`) is still alive and will now access memory that has been deallocated.  Time to look at your design, especially that reference counting variable (which is not really being shared by the instances).

Comment: Tip: don't re-invent the wheel (except perhaps to the extent required by your assignment). Keeping track of a reference count and freeing memory when the reference count reaches zero is something `shared_ptr` already does, and you can make use of it in your own class.

Comment: ***a.rename ("John", "Anderson"); // should rename both 'a' and 'b'*** I would expect rename to not change 'b' if you are doing a copy on write.

Comment: drescherjm: yes, that is the next step, so far I was just going for a classic shallow copy (sorry, I should have been more clear about that)
hvd: yes, I have been doing some research since asking this question and now I see that I should carry this information in a pointer in the middle. thanks for pointing that out
PaulMcKenzie: thanks for that piece of code, will definitely help

Answer (score 2):

Your design is flawed.  You need to implement the reference count on the character data itself, not on the individual `CPerson` objects, as they are not sharing a single reference count variable with each other.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct SPersonData
{
    string m_name;
    string m_surname;
    int m_refcnt;

    SPersonData() : m_refcnt(0) {}

    void incRef() { ++m_refcnt; }
    void decRef() { if (--m_refcnt == 0) delete this; }
};

class CPerson
{
private:
    SPersonData *m_data;

public:
    CPerson ();
    CPerson (const CPerson&);
    ~CPerson (); 

    CPerson& operator= (const CPerson&);

    string getName() const;
    string getSurname() const;

    void rename (const string&, const string&);
};

CPerson::CPerson ()
    : m_data(NULL) {}

CPerson::CPerson (const CPerson& src)
    : m_data (src.m_data)
{
    if (m_data) m_data->incRef();
}

CPerson::~CPerson ()
{
    if (m_data) m_data->decRef();
}

CPerson& operator= (const CPerson &src)
{
    if (this != &src)
    {
        if (m_data) m_data->decRef();
        m_data = src.m_data;
        if (m_data) m_data->incRef();
    }    
    return *this;
}

string CPerson::getName() const
{
    if (m_data) return m_data->m_name;
    return string();
}

string CPerson::getSurname() const
{ 
    if (m_data) return m_data->m_surname;
    return string();
}

void CPerson::rename (const string &name, const string &surname)
{
    if ((m_data) && (m_data->m_refcnt > 1))
    {
        m_data->decRef(); 
        m_data = NULL;
    }

    if (!m_data)
    {
        m_data = new SPersonData;
        m_data->incRef();
    }

    m_data->m_name = name;
    m_data->m_surname = surname;
}
```

Which can be greatly simplified in C++11 and later by using `std::shared_ptr` to manage the reference count:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

struct SPersonData
{
    string m_name;
    string m_surname;
};

class CPerson
{
public:
    shared_ptr<SPersonData> m_data;

    string getName() const;
    string getSurname() const;

    void rename (const string&, const string&);
};

string CPerson::getName() const
{
    if (m_data) return m_data->m_name;
    return string();
}

string CPerson::getSurname() const
{ 
    if (m_data) return m_data->m_surname;
    return string();
}

void CPerson::rename (const string &name, const string &surname)
{
    if (!((m_data) && m_data.unique()))
        m_data = make_shared<SPersonData>(); 

    m_data->m_name = name;
    m_data->m_surname = surname;
}
```

Either way, your test would then look like this:

```
int main ()
{
    CPerson a;
    a.rename ("Jack", "Smith");
    cout << a.getName() << " " << a.getSurname() << endl;

    CPerson b(a);
    cout << a.getName() << " " << a.getSurname() << endl;
    cout << b.getName() << " " << b.getSurname() << endl;
    // good so far...

    a.rename ("John", "Anderson"); // should rename only 'a' not 'b'
    cout << a.getName() << " " << a.getSurname() << endl;
    cout << b.getName() << " " << b.getSurname() << endl;   

    return  0;
}
```

Comment: i think the reference count can be put into the `class CPerson` ,as long as we use `int* ref=new int` instead of `int ref`

Comment: and that's how the smart pointers does,because a smart pointer could not put a reference counting into user-defined class

Comment: @bigxiao look at the actual implementation of `shared_ptr`. It wraps user-defined data inside a control block that also holds the reference count, and then passes a pointer to the control block around. Similar to how the code in my answer does.

Comment: Where can i see the actual implementation of shared_ptr?Is there a website somewhrere?

Comment: @bigxiao look at the source code for whatever STL comes with your compiler tool chain. The STL is hugely templated, so it is comprised mostly of header-only implementations. Look at the contents of the `<memory>` header.